# Magento 2 The information or error messages always remain displayed even after a change of page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, messages, global-messages

The information or error messages always remain displayed even after a change of page, so once I get to the cart I have 5 or 6 messages that are still present, how to put a lifetime to the messages in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve isssue from below referance link:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Error-Success-message-not-showing-on-one-page-in-custom-module/td-p/72823

I was using

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
```

for the javascript validation.
I changed it to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```